# Loading async data into React component

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

I need to asynchronously load external data into my React component. [The documentation here provides the following code example.](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#fetching-external-data)

```
// After
class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    externalData: null,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this._asyncRequest = loadMyAsyncData().then(
      externalData => {
        this._asyncRequest = null;
        this.setState({externalData});
      }
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this._asyncRequest) {
      this._asyncRequest.cancel();
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.externalData === null) {
      // Render loading state ...
    } else {
      // Render real UI ...
    }
  }
}
```

But what might `loadMyAsyncData()` look like to make it "thenable?" I would imagine it might use `async/await`?

Can someone provide an example?

Comment: It would just be a function that returns a promise, and inside the promise you have an API call that resolves/rejects the promise based on the API response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be "thenable `loadMyAsyncData` should return a `Promise`.

Here's an example loadMyAsyncData returning a promise and using `setTimeout` to delay resolving the promise after 1 second

```
const loadMyAsyncData = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve({
    example: "value"
  }), 1000)
})
```

you can use the code above `this._asyncRequest = loadMyAsyncData().then( ..... )` or use async/await instead

```
async componentDidMount() {
  this._asyncRequest = loadMyAsyncData()
  const externalData = await this._asyncRequest;
  this._asyncRequest = null;
  this.setState({externalData});
}
```

[codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/lrvwm88pv7)

Comment: Thanks. +1. I really appreciate the codesandbox example. Quick question. Is there any way to use `async/await` to define `loadMyAsyncData()` or does it have to use the `new Promise()` syntax?

Comment: @Mowzer it depends on the implementation, but in this case we need use `new Promise()`

Comment: Is that because it needs to return a promise? And `async/await` does not return a promise?